# Targeting An Element On a Specific URL

Tags: php, javascript

I need to run an alternate header on a single top-level Joomla page.
From what I can see, unlike Wordpress Joomla doesn't assign an ID to individual pages, making this a pain.

I'm wondering if I can target the element using javascript or something. Like choosing the base URL of the page and targeting the element on the page?

This would be better as it would mean I don't have to create an additional include, which would be overridden by the next template update anyway.

Any guidance on helping me solve this problem would be really helpful.

Comment: Actually resolved this myself - In the menu configuration there is an option to add a page class. Only issue now is changing the logo to an alternative version.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by finding an option in the individual menu item to add a class to the body element. This allowed me to target a specific page.